# Deployment of google cloud function takes forever

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem with deployment of Google Cloud Function. Basically, it stuck in a state `DEPLOY_IN_PROGRESS` and I cannot do anything with this. I tried to delete the function using `gcloud` but the message I'm getting:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.delete) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[An operation on function fn-dev in region europe-west3 in project demo is already in progress. Please try again later.
```

Not sure what I can do with this?

Comment: Typically this means something is not working correctly in your deployment. You will have to wait for everything to timeout. Check Stackdriver for messages.

Comment: As @JohnHanley said, if you see any error message in SD please took at this doc to troubleshoot https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Did it fail in the end? What was the error message?

Comment: One possible reason for this issue is when the Cloud Function does not have enough memory to deploy: it will get stuck until the timeout is reached.